My air conditioner does not drain water
I checked my AC today and found lots of water around it. A guy on Quora suggests that the refrigerant is low. Can someone please give me some advice? Thanks.


That is a classic case of the drain line being clogged.
Usually it's clogged with gunky stuff that has grown in the condensate (water) in the drain line.
Find the termination of the drain.  It is outside the house or drains to another drain in the basement or garage.  Use a shop vac to suck out what you can. A rag held tight around the vac hose and AC drain will help close suction.
If that doesn't work you will have to find the drain at the Air handler and disconnect it so you can add air to blow it out.  The exhaust from a shop vac or a pump sprayer can be used.
If both those attempts fail, you will need to call an AC pro.  They have encountered this problem many times and have way to clean the drain out.
BTW- this has nothing to do with low freon unless the system was freezing. If it was, then you would have a symptoms of poor cooling from low air flow.
